# pthread_create exits the program after finishing function

Tags: linux, gcc, pthreads

I try to create program that takes power readings about 10 times in one second and start a new thread every second/minute to update mysql database while the main program continues taking readings. But after I use pthread_create function runs once and then program seems to exit. It is my first time trying to do something with pthread and obviously I am doing something wrong. Please help because it seems smart to use new thread to update mysql, so it will not interrupt main program. I will add my code (bit that are important I think)

the function:

```
void *showreadout(float readout,int l, int s) {
  printf("readout: %f loops: %i sec: %i\n",readout,l,s);
  return NULL;
}
```

and stuff from main:

```
      pthread_t thread;
      int p = 0, startminute = currentminute(),startsec,u;
      float secreadout;

      while (startminute == currentminute()) {
        startsec = currentsec();
        u = 0;
        secreadout = 0;
        while (startsec == currentsec()) {
          secreadout += doloop(pinnumber);
          u++;
        }
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, showreadout(secreadout/u,u, startsec), NULL);
        p++;
      }
```

Comment: suggest rebuilding your software with `gcc -Wall -Wextra` and resolve issues; note that `pthread_create()` needs a pointer to a start routine, not the return value from a call

Comment: ```gcc -Wall -Wextra``` gives no warnings at all, everything seems to be in check. Sorry for being little silly but what do you mean exactly with that ```phtread_create()``` needs pointer not return value from call, can you give example (so I can copy'n'paste it)

Comment: I figured it out I think :) ... before ```phtread_create()``` I make variables I use in function global like ```gsecreadout = secreadout/u;``` and in that function I use global variables ... I dont know is it the right way but it seems to work :) ... thank you for pointing it out

Comment: And your code overwrites the value in thread every time it calls pthread_create, leaving you no way to join the older copies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to send variables with `pthread_create()` to my function and it worked once but then things seemed to go "tits up" or rather the program just stopped.

I solved it by making global variable for the readout and updated it after end of each second before calling my function with `pthread_create()` and using global variable in my function. I dont know is it the right way to approach it but it seems to work.

Comment: The real problem is that `showreadout(secreadout/u,u, startsec)` is a function call, not a function pointer. But since it returns a `void*` C allows it. And then pthread_create tries to execute a NULL pointer as a function?